# Nginx or PHP FPM ignores memory_limit in php.ini

Tags: nginx, php

Server info: Ubuntu Server, Nginx, PHP FPM

in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` I have: `memory_limit = 512M`
in `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` I have: `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M`

```
php_value[memory_limit] = 512M
```

### My phpinfo looks like:

PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6

### System Build Date

Linux snserver 3.2.0-40-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 21:22:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 Mar 11 2013 14:34:24

### Server API

`FPM/FastCGI`

### Virtual Directory Support

disabled

### Configuration File (php.ini) Path

```
/etc/php5/fpm
```

### Loaded Configuration File

`/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

Scan this dir for additional .ini files
`/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d`

### Additional `.ini` files parsed

`/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/curl.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/gd.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/memcache.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini`
...

This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10
Copyright (c) 2006-2007 Hardened-PHP Project Copyright (c) 2007-2009 SektionEins GmbH

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

...

### memory_limit

128M

### upload_max_filesize

20M

in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
    user www-data;

worker_processes 2;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    ##

    # Basic Settings

    ##
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;

    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    proxy_buffers 4 512k;

    proxy_buffer_size 256k;

    proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;

    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;

    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 300;

    keepalive_requests 50;

    #ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;

        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        #ssl_protocols TLSv1;

        #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        #ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

---

The problem is when i change  `upload_max_filesize` size then the `phpinfo` will show the new value, but when I change `memory_limit` then nothing changes. 
I guess in somewhere the memory_limit is overwrited. But i cannot find it. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take Nginx out of the picture, it just passes the request on, it's in php-fpm running your php code.

you might check your suhosin settings, suhosin.memory_limit.

when you see your phpinfo output there should be 2 columns, master and local for memory_limit, what do these each show?

128M is the default for memory_limit in php 5.3

Answer (score 35):

In `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` I have `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M`

This works for me.

Comment: For me as well, changing it in php.ini wasn't enough, even though it was picked up according to ```phpinfo()``` (using php 5.4.26)

Comment: Don't forget to restart php-fpm and nginx after you make these edits.

Comment: in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf  removed  php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M after php5-fpm restart in then changes for memory_limit in the /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini file

Comment: As per pilot's answer elsewhere, good idea to fully stop/start php-fpm rather than restart, so you can be sure all the old processes have cleared.

Comment: After several days of researching the problem, you found the key to the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 17):

The problem may be in **fpm** the process duplication, even you change your /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini it was not effect.

- Stop php5-fpm with (ubuntu): sudo service php5-fpm stop
- check that no more fpm processes: sudo ps ax | grep fpm
- if any kill it all with: sudo kill -9 pid
- be sure that you kill all fpm processes
- restart: sudo service php5-fpm restart

Comment: This worked for me, there were 3 duplicate fpm processes running because of which it was not taking the changed value until you kill all the fpm processes and restart php5-fpm

Comment: Best to perform this as a script for minimum downtime in production.

Answer (score 8):

For me it also ignored php.ini and I had to do the following:

```
vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 10000M ;128M
```

Then restart php-fpm:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: thanks, this was my problem and it help solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Just FYI,

you should also check in /etc/php5/fpm/**pool.d** for any files.

It just happened to me that no matter what I wrote on /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf it would get overrided by /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf !

So if none of the above answers are not working for you, you should check this (I just lost half hour to this).

Answer (score 3):

Also encountered this now and wanted to increase memory of our server in a DigitalOcean droplet

To summarize, here is what I did

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

-- press Ctrl-W to do a search in nano text editor
-- if php_admin_value[memory_limit] is there, change it
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M

sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

You don't need to restart nginx, just restarting **php** would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is daft but I had memory_limit set to 2GB, which isn't understood. When I changed that to 2000M it worked!

Comment: Maybe need to set 2G, instead of 2GB

Answer (score 0):

The file I needed to edit was /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini - found that out by running `phpinfo()` **in the script itself** rather than viewing it through the browser - `nginx`.

`phpinfo()` in the browser indicated Loaded Configuration File `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini`

`phpinfo()` in the console indicated Loaded Configuration File `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini`

Not sure why, Im not investigating further rn, just glad that I found it