# Is there any value range limit for memory_limit in php 5.6?

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

we have a UAT environment running with nginx and php-fpm. I was trying to increase the memory_limit to 2GB by changing the php.ini, .htaccess

After restarting the nginx and php-fpm, checked the phpinfo() and seeing that those changes are not taking affect on the environment.

May I know the reason for this?

Comment: This might be of some help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962634/nginx-or-php-fpm-ignores-memory-limit-in-php-ini

Comment: For what exactly do you need 2GB memory PHP processes? Using PHP might not be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

better puts the configs here,as I tested,it is all ok,when I set the limit 2G,it displays 2G when echo info,restart the php service required