# Memory limit is ignored in Centos 7.5

Tags: php, memory-limit

I made changes to my php.ini file to increase the `memory limit` from `128M` to `512M`

I found the correct php.ini file using phpinfo(); -> `'/opt/php71m/custom/php-fpm.ini'`
but the change is igonred.

Even when I set it using `ini_set('memory_limit','512M')`; it doesn't work again.

php --ini gives me another `php.ini` file `'/etc/php.ini'` and also a bunch of other `ini` files that they dont have this '`memory_limit`' in them , I made changes in that file too but still no help.

php -i |grep `memory_limit` tells me that it's set to `512M`

But when I run my script I get the fatal error that says `memory` limit is `128M`

> ini_get('memory_limit') gives me 128M

where is the problem?

these are the content of my configuration files:
first file: '/etc/php.ini'

```
;;; begin content - please not remove this line


[PHP]
;### MR -- generic (the same on all php 5.x version)
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
y2k_compliance = On
unserialize_callback_func=
disable_classes =
expose_php = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
;error_reporting = E_ALL
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
gpc_order = "GPC"
include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear/"
doc_root =
user_dir =
extension_dir = /usr/lib64/php/modules
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp/
default_socket_timeout = 60
date.timezone = Asia/Tehran
default_charset = "utf-8"

;### MR -- certain apps not work if 0 (ex: roundcube)
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
;### MR -- certain apps not work if 1 (ex: wordpress in apache or proxy)
cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0

;### MR -- specific for php 5.3+
auto_globals_jit = On
zlib.output_compression = off
zlib.output_compression_level = 6
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
unserialize_callback_func =
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
html_errors = On
auto_append_file =

;### MR -- custom setting (handle by kloxo)
disable_functions = exec,passthru,system,proc_open,popen,show_source
display_errors = off
file_uploads = on
upload_max_filesize = 16M
log_errors = off
error_log = /var/log/php-error.log
output_buffering = off
register_argc_argv = on
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 5
post_max_size = 32M
memory_limit = 512M
allow_url_fopen = on
allow_url_include = off
session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session
cgi.force_redirect = on
;sendmail_from = 
enable_dl = on
max_input_vars = 3000

;### MR -- deprecated/disabled on php 5.3+
;;register_long_arrays = Off

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables = Off

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

[Java]

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1 

[MySQL]
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[mSQL]
msql.max_persistent = -1
msql.max_links = -1

[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase]
sybase.allow_persistent = On
sybase.max_persistent = -1
sybase.max_links = -1
sybase.min_error_severity = 10
sybase.min_message_severity = 10
sybase.compatability_mode = Off

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[dbx]
dbx.colnames_case = "lowercase"

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini

[Informix]
ifx.default_host =
ifx.default_user =
ifx.default_password =
ifx.allow_persistent = On
ifx.max_persistent = -1
ifx.max_links = -1
ifx.textasvarchar = 0
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
ifx.charasvarchar = 0
ifx.blobinfile = 0
ifx.nullformat = 0

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Assertion]

[Ingres II]
ingres.allow_persistent = On
ingres.max_persistent = -1
ingres.max_links = -1
ingres.default_database =
ingres.default_user =
ingres.default_password =

[Verisign Payflow Pro]
pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"
pfpro.defaultport = 443
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30

[Sockets]
sockets.use_system_read = On

[com]

[Printer]

[mbstring]

[FrontBase]

[Crack]

[exif]

;### MR -- exist on php 5.3+
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On

[Date]

[filter]

[iconv]

[intl]

[sqlite]

[sqlite3]

[Pcre]

[Pdo]

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]

[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

[OCI8]

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5

[sysvshm]

[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1

[mcrypt]

[dba]

;;; end content - please not remove this line
```

second file '/opt/php71m/custom/php-fpm.ini':

```
;;; begin content - please not remove this line


[PHP]
;### MR -- generic (the same on all php 5.x version)
engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
y2k_compliance = On
unserialize_callback_func=
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
;safe_mode_gid = Off
;safe_mode_include_dir =
;safe_mode_exec_dir =
;safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
;safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_classes =
expose_php = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
;error_reporting = E_ALL
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
gpc_order = "GPC"
include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear/"
doc_root =
user_dir =
extension_dir = /opt/php71m/usr/lib/php/modules
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp/
default_socket_timeout = 60
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
default_charset = "utf-8"

;### MR -- certain apps not work if 0 (ex: roundcube)
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
;### MR -- certain apps not work if 1 (ex: wordpress in apache or proxy)
cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0

;### MR -- custom setting (handle by kloxo)
;disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,show_source
;register_globals = off
display_errors = off
file_uploads = on
upload_max_filesize = 64M
;upload_max_filesize = 2000M
log_errors = off
error_log = /var/log/php71m-error.log
output_buffering = off
register_argc_argv = on
;magic_quotes_gpc = off
;magic_quotes_runtime = off
;magic_quotes_sybase = off
mysql.allow_persistent = off
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit= 256M
post_max_size = 64M
;max_execution_time = 3000000
;max_input_time = 60000
;memory_limit = -1
;post_max_size = 2000M
allow_url_fopen = on
allow_url_include = on
session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session
cgi.force_redirect = on
;sendmail_from = 
;safe_mode = off
enable_dl = on

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables = Off

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

[Java]

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1 

[MySQL]
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[mSQL]
msql.max_persistent = -1
msql.max_links = -1

[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase]
sybase.allow_persistent = On
sybase.max_persistent = -1
sybase.max_links = -1
sybase.min_error_severity = 10
sybase.min_message_severity = 10
sybase.compatability_mode = Off

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[dbx]
dbx.colnames_case = "lowercase"

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini

[Informix]
ifx.default_host =
ifx.default_user =
ifx.default_password =
ifx.allow_persistent = On
ifx.max_persistent = -1
ifx.max_links = -1
ifx.textasvarchar = 0
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
ifx.charasvarchar = 0
ifx.blobinfile = 0
ifx.nullformat = 0

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Assertion]

[Ingres II]
ingres.allow_persistent = On
ingres.max_persistent = -1
ingres.max_links = -1
ingres.default_database =
ingres.default_user =
ingres.default_password =

[Verisign Payflow Pro]
pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"
pfpro.defaultport = 443
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30

[Sockets]
sockets.use_system_read = On

[com]

[Printer]

[mbstring]

[FrontBase]

[Crack]

[exif]

;### MR -- exist on php 5.3+
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On

[Date]

[filter]

[iconv]

[intl]

[sqlite]

[sqlite3]

[Pcre]
pcre.backtrack_limit=100000
pcre.recursion_limit=100000

[Pdo]

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]

[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

[OCI8]

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5

[sysvshm]

[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1

[mcrypt]

[dba]

;;; end content - please not remove this line
```

Comment: Did you restart httpd after your php.ini changes?

Comment: @Gudgip restarted the whole server, I'm using nginx as webserver

Comment: Ok, try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962634/nginx-or-php-fpm-ignores-memory-limit-in-php-ini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx or PHP FPM ignores memory\_limit in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962634/nginx-or-php-fpm-ignores-memory-limit-in-php-ini)